# Inserting an E notation double into a decimal column

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a number in C# which is `double longitude =1.041970849797e-05`.
When I try to insert it into a `decimal(9,6)` column, I get the error message:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

How do I correctly save the above as a decimal?

**C# Application Code:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double lat=1.041970849797e-05;
    insertRecs(lat);
}

private static void insertRecs(double latitude)
{
    Int32 rowsAffected = 0;
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_temp", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 90;
        try
        {
            rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception in Insertrecords ");
            Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**SQL Stored Procedure:**

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_temp]
    --The parameters for the stored procedure
    @latitude decimal(9,6)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into temptest(latitude) values(@latitude);
END
```

Comment: Can you show us the insert query you are using?

Comment: decimal(9,6) is not large enough to hold the data you want to insert

Comment: Your number is `1.041970849797×10^(-5)` which is `0.00001041970849797` in decimal. This wouldn't retain accuracy when inserted into a `decimal(9,6)` column.  Without seeing any code however we won't be able to tell you why you get that error message.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the sample of code you gave us you don't actually map the `latitude` variable when running the Stored Procedure.

You would need to add a couple of lines like so:

```
SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@latitude", SqlDbType.Decimal);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.Value = latitude;
```

And edited into your code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_temp", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 90;

    // Map the parameters into the Stored Procedure
    SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@latitude", SqlDbType.Decimal);
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.Value = latitude;

    try
    {
        rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ep)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception in Insertrecords ");
        Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
    }
}
```